# how can i better write these function to make sense

Tags: python, list, sum

I intend writing a function which i can use to sum up all numbers of an list having two digit. for example :

```
a=[1,2,11,100,10]

should return 21 since 11 and 10 of the list are having two digits
```

i also want the range of number to be (0,1,2,...100000)

```
def solution(A):
    for integer in A:
        if integer > 9 and integer <100:
            two_digits_array.append(integer)
    return sum( two_digits_array )
```

I guess it was alright, so on testing :

```
Example test: numbers=  [47, 1900, 1, 90, 45]
print (solution(numbers))
wow it works perfectly and returns 182
```

but i tried these :

```
q= [1, 1000, 80, -91]
WRONG ANSWER (got 80 expected -11)
```

how can i go about it please and why the failure.

Comment: Looks like numbers from -10 to -99 are also considered as having two digits. So in your for-loop you have to check: "if integer > 9 and integer < 100 or integer < -9 and integer > -100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the numbers greater than 9 and less than 100. Try this:

> if integer > 9 and integer <100 or integer > -100 and integer < -9:

Comment: Logic is right but why to write a function and create extra overhead instead you can yield the result in one line using the builtins

Comment: @binayr - it's not always about using built-in methods and one-liners. If question author is asking help for homework (what it looks like) then helping to fix its code is better than just providing an answer without any explanations. I highly dislike Stackoverflow answers that just are "heres my code, it just works, use this". You really help person if you help him improve.

Answer (score 4):

Why making it so hard? You can simply use a generator with a filter and pass that generator to the `sum(..)` builtin. Like:

```
def solution(A):
    return sum(x for x in A if -100 < x < -9 or 9 < x < 100)
```

Or as [@PawełKordowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855863/how-can-i-better-write-these-function-to-make-sense/42855923#comment72817929_42855923) suggests, use `abs(..)` to make the condition more elegant:

```
def solution(A):
    return sum(x for x in A if 9 < abs(x) < 100)
```

No need to declare an additional array (that will only consume memory).

The `<expr> for <var> in <iterable> if <condition>` is a *generator*: it generates *lazily* a sequence of numbers by applying `<expr>` on the `<var>` for every element in `<iterable>` if the `<condition>` is met.

Comment: You can use `abs` to make the constaint shorter

Comment: Wonder how this compares to `len(str(x)) == 2`, probably converting to str is slower but not sure because of the chaining...

Comment: Your answer is nice, but it looks like the question is about someone's homework. Providing just some working code for it isn't the best idea imo.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: usually a conversion to a string is indeed rather expensive. Furthermore `-10` will have `len('-10') == 3`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `len(str(x)) == 2` does not take into account the negative numbers, you should use `len(str(abs(x))) == 2` but I don't think it is efficient

Comment: @PawełKordowski Yes I missed the `abs()` call, and I agree it's probably worse but given the chained 2 comparison (and 2 `abs()` calls), I just wondered, probably should `timeit` to be sure

Comment: @Chris_Rands: in chaining, the expressions are evaluated only **once**. So Python calculates `abs(x)` only once, stores it in an accumulator and performs the two conditions on that result, as is written [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: Interesting Willem, thanks, I didn't know that optimization occured

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
print sum(filter(lambda x: (x<100 and x>9) or (x>-100 and x<-9), a))
```

assuming a is the list.

Comment: thank...for reaching out for my aid..it works for me now with all test cases..am so much grateful

Answer (score 2):

Please use this updated script

```
def solution(A):
    for integer in A:
        if (integer > 9 and integer < 100) or (integer > -100 and integer < -9):
            two_digits_array.append(integer)
    return sum( two_digits_array )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use len() for calculating the no of digits:

```
ans=0
for i in a:
    if(len(str(abs(i)))==2:
        ans+=i
return ans
```